# retrieve the id PDO if a value already exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables which are linked with many many relationship,Normally I work with Mysqli for querying,but now for some reasons I have to use PDO,So my problem is 1st to check if a value doesn't exists, to add it in a table **tag**,and if not to take the **id** of the value and add the related data in the join data.

**tag-tagmap-post** a tag can belong to many posts,and a post can have many tags I try this but when a tag name already exists I can't retrieve the id of the tag.

```
 $sql = "
    INSERT INTO tag (name)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT :name) AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM tag WHERE name =:name
    ) LIMIT 1";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $post->name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $test=$post->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        //echo json_encode($post); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }

    $sql2="INSERT INTO tagmap (tag_id,post_id,user_id) VALUES(:id2,:post_id,:id)";//
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql2);  
        $stmt->bindParam("id2", $test);//tag id
        $stmt->bindParam("post_id", $post->post_id);//post_id
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$post2->id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$test)); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: INSERT with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, then SELECT tag.id. It's best to avoid using PDO::lastInsertId().

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

That said, the insertion query itself is over-complicated (and contains syntax errors: there is no `LIMIT` clause in the `INSERT` syntax).  You could instead:

1. define a [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/constraint-primary-key.html) key over `(name)` in the `tag` table:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE tag ADD UNIQUE (name);
   ```
2. use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (?)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
   ```

   This will ensure that `$db->lastInsertId()` returns the ID of the relevant record whether it has been newly inserted or it already existed.